# how to remove spaces in vector in c++

Tags: c++, stl

Below is the program I coded for to split the string and store in a vector.
How can I retrive the specifics fields from the string and again concatenate expected string using pipeline(|) symbol.

```
   #include <iostream> 
   #include <vector>
   #include <string>
   #include <sstream>
   using namespace std;

    vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter)
    {
    vector<string> internal;
    stringstream ss(str); 
    string tok;
    while(getline(ss, tok, delimiter)) 
    {
       internal.push_back(tok);
     }
    return internal;
   }

  int main(int argc, char **argv) 
  {
    string myCSV = "Event#:11918124|1234|67893|USD||||444400090|||||302|45|USA|||||";
    vector<string> sep = split(myCSV, '|');
    for(int i = 0; i < sep.size(); ++i);
     cout << sep[0] << "|" << sep[3] << "|" << sep[7] << "|" << sep[14] << endl;
   }
```

output:

```
Event#:11918124                                                           
1234                                                                         
67893                                                                        

USD                                                                                                                
444400090                                      

302                                                                                                                                                                                             
45                                                                                                                                       
USA
```

Expected Output:

```
Event#:11918124|USD|444400090|USA
```

Can anyone please help me out in c++.I am new to c++

Comment: spaces aren't `|`, That code appears to be doing what you asked it to. And if you want everything on one line, what send `endl` after each output element?

Answer (score 1):

All that you need to do is to concatenate needed fields of your record. They are always present at the same indexes (0, 3, 7, 14).
So in your case it's as easy as:

```
cout << sep[0] << "|" << sep[3] << "|" << sep[7] << "|" << sep[14] << endl;
```

btw, your "output:" to your code is wrong.

Comment: after modyfying the code by adding semicolon to the forloop i am able to see the expected output.Thank you for your help